# Font doesnt work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts

I added custom fonts in my rails app, in a folder webfonts in assets.

In my file _variables.scss (in the folder stylesheets/config), I added this code:

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/2ff6c8");


@font-face {font-family: 'Variable-Regular';
  src: url('webfonts/2FF6C8_0_0.eot');
  src: url('webfonts/2FF6C8_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('webfonts/2FF6C8_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('webfonts/2FF6C8_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
  url('webfonts/2FF6C8_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

It works in my development environnement, but not in my production environnement. What should I do to make it work on Heroku?

Comment: are these files fetched post-deploy, or are they part of the deployment slug? Because heroku dynos reset to whatever was in their slug when they wake up. Any files you generated after that will *not* exist when the dyno wakes up

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exact error. Maybe there are not proper headers and thus font files are not loading. You could try [font_assets gem](https://github.com/ericallam/font_assets) in this case.